# Почему вызов QFileDialog::getSaveFileName() сбрасывает обработчик сообщений в Qt в Astra Linux?

Tags: c++, qt, astra-linux

Вызов QFileDialog::getSaveFileName() сбрасывает обработчик сообщений в Qt в Astra Linux

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>

QtMessageHandler defaultHandler;

void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    auto str = msg;
    str.append(" handled");
    defaultHandler(type, context, str);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "test0";
    defaultHandler = qInstallMessageHandler(messageHandler);
    qDebug() << "test1";
    QFileDialog::getSaveFileName();
    qDebug() << "test2";
}
```

output in windows

```
test0
test1 handled
test2 handled
```

output in astra linux

```
test0
test1 handled
warning: QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
debug: test2
```

Comment: Помогло использование QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog.

Comment: или QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontUseNativeDialogs);